# Simplifying large, expanded sums

Tags: summation, expected-value, symmetric-functions

Consider the following expression:

$$
D = \left[\sum_{m=1}^M \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{R}} \sum_{r=1}^R x^{p_1}_{R(m-1)+r}\right)^2\right]
\left[\sum_{m=1}^M \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{R}} \sum_{r=1}^R x^{p_2}_{R(m-1)+r}\right)^2\right] - 
\left[\sum_{m=1}^M \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{R}} \sum_{r=1}^R x^{p_1}_{R(m-1)+r}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{R}} \sum_{r=1}^R x^{p_2}_{R(m-1)+r}\right) \right]^2
$$

where all $x$ are i.i.d random variables (zero-mean Gaussian for simplicity). I am seeking $\mathbb{E}[ D^q ]$ (e.g. $q=1$ and $q=2$).

The expectation operator $\mathbb{E}$ is linear and can be applied by expanding the entire sum, grouping the same $x$ together and replacing them with their moments.

To understand better what I mean consider the much simplified expression with $R=1$:

$$
D = \left(\sum_{m=1}^M x^{2 p_1}_{m} \right)
\left(\sum_{m=1}^M x^{2p_2}_{m}\right) - 
\left(\sum_{m=1}^M x^{p_1+p_2}_{m} \right)^2 = \sum_{m_1=1}^M \sum_{m_2=1}^M \left(
x^{2 p_1}_{m_1}x^{2 p_2}_{m_2} - x^{p_1+p_2}_{m_1}x^{p_1+p_2}_{m_2}
\right)
$$

The two sums can be easily analyzed for the 2 cases $m_1=m_2=m$ and $m_1\neq m_2$ to yield:

$$
\mathbb{E}(D)=M(M-1) [ \mu(2p_1)\mu(2p_2) - \mu^2(p_1+p_2) ]
$$

This approach generalizes to higher order sums using *symmetric functions*. However, for $R>1$ the expression is not symmetric any more.

Another approach I follwed was to find a pattern in the expanded sum (e.g., using Mathematica). However, this becomes infeasible. For example, $\mathbb{E}[D]$ expands to a 6-fold sum and $\mathbb{E}[D^2]$ to a 12-fold sum. If $M=R=4$ the expanded sum has already $4^{12}=16777216$ terms - even through they collapse to just a handfull terms when replacing them with their moments. However, for finding a patterns I would need to sweep $M$ and $R$ at least between one and 10 or so.

Any thoughts on how to tackle this sum?

Comment: Since you tried symbolic approaches and failed, you should stick to using numeric values.

Comment: Are you giving a recommendation or are you saying that it seems hopeless that there even exists a way to do this analytically? I have tons of numerical simulations already for which I don't even need this $D$ expression. But I want to show the conditions and boundaries under which my results are valid. For numerics, I have to sweep over all possible parameters to ensure to capture all possible combinations. (Note: $D$ is just part of a larger piece)